# Setting iframe src via JS isnt working specifically for sharepoint

Tags: javascript, iframe, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, content-security-policy

Setting src directly in iframe is working as expected

I'm trying to embed a Sharepoint document here.

For eg

```html
<iframe src="https://rocketlane123-my.sharepoint.com/personal/lokeshkannan_rocketlane123_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={8822527b-0c56-44f9-8263-40c737db903c}&amp;action=embedview"
      width="476px"
      height="288px" />
```

Whereas when I set the src in the script it's failing

```html
<iframe id="x" width="476px" height="288px"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('x').src = "https://rocketlane123-my.sharepoint.com/personal/lokeshkannan_rocketlane123_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={8822527b-0c56-44f9-8263-40c737db903c}&amp;action=embedview";
</script>
```

[image: Passing vs failing]

This happens explicitly with SharePoint. So I would like to understand a couple of things here.

```
1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Is there any CSP headers which block the parent from adding via JS?
3. Is there any official way from SharePoint to allow this? 
3. Is there any way to hack this?
```

Thanks in advance.

Since this happens across chrome, safari and firefox I think it's not a bug in a specific browser.

Answer (score 2):

Trying this in Firefox yields this error message:

> To protect your security, login.microsoftonline.com will not allow
> Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see
> this page, you need to open it in a new window.

Opening the console gives this message:

> The loading of [*url*] in a frame is denied by “X-Frame-Options“
> directive set to “DENY“.

This is a header that's set by `login.microsoft.com` to disable embedding the link as an iframe.

This link details this design choice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/cannot-display-sharepoint-pages-in-iframe

The link mentions you can override the behavior by setting 'AllowFraming', though it doesn't recommend it, as there may be site-breaking changes by embedding it.

A guide to use this feature can be found at [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-public-site-can-not-be-viewed-in-a-page/65ba2f7b-ce94-4df4-a7d1-1496f8b67dab)

Comment: Very useful. although setting src directly without using JS works as excepted. Is it also expected behaviour?

Comment: It is strange, to me; I would expect the behavior to be the same. In addition, I noticed that it also loads if you set the URL via innerHTML, for example `var container = document.createElement('div'); container.innerHTML = '<iframe src="[url here]"></iframe>'; document.body.appendChild(container);` Why the security policy doesn't seem to activate here is a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: yup! that's why I raised this question. I hope my question seems a bit unclear. In fact, it's happening across all browsers.

Comment: @ChandraKumar, investigating this a little further, it looks when setting the iframe src via js (and also directly navigating in browser), your `sharepoint.com` url redirects to a `login.microsoft.net` url which then redirects to a `login.microsoftonline.com` url. The last two links seem to disable iframe embedding. When you set the src directly in an iframe via HTML, the sharepoint.com url isn't redirected, and that link doesn't have the `X-Frame-Options` header set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in, javascript amp; should not represent as &.

Change your link to

```
<body>
    <iframe id="x" width="476px" height="288px"></iframe>
    
    <script>
    document.getElementById('x').src = "https://rocketlane123.sharepoint.com/sites/MyDocsforSP/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={6d327004-5d52-4e42-9707-c964631f8e65}&action=embedview";
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't work..

Comment: Updated the iframe URL so you can test on your local machine.